# Is "aim for" a formal structure?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, writing

When I'm writing a very formal academic article or a text at work, I make use of "aim at" in it. My question is: Can I use "aim for" as alternative formal option in my texts?

Comment: I could see it working, for example after a detailed explanation of a goal, you could summarize, e.g., "We will be aiming for a 3% reduction of ...."  By the way, was "aim at" a typo, or were you asking about this as well?

Comment: I see no reason why not. JSTOR turns up lots of results for both collocations. That said, it is hard to gauge appropriateness without examples or further explanation.

Comment: Unless pointing a bow and arrow or a firearm, trying to hit my brother in the head with a shoe, or something along those lines and *not* talking about some abstract goal, I would always say "aim for" rather than "aim at."  At the gun range, I could say either "I'm aiming at the bull's eye" or "I'm aiming for the bull's eye," but if I'm talking about becoming a doctor, I will always say, "I'm aiming for becoming a doctor," not "I'm aiming at becoming a doctor."

Comment: They can convey different ideas. Use whichever is appropriate.